# how can I have picture to my ontology

Tags: ontology, protege, protege4

How can I have a picture for my `ontology` where you can read the names of all content (class, object properties and data properties) using `protege`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the OntoGraph or OWLViz tab in Protege editor. From there, you can save the graph (if that's what you want).

Comment: this plug in give me the graph just for class. i need graph for all the components of the ontology, for example Vowl plug in give mi the graph but I can't have it like photo

Comment: In order to save the graph like an image, you can use the options when you click on OntoGraf tab. If you take a closer look, there are various icons appearing for different options. One of these is a camera for exporting the graph as image. Use it to save in any format you wish.

Comment: For answer to your all components of ontology question, Protege allows only classes & individuals to be treated as nodes in the graph. Double-click (or click on the + sign) of any class & all its subclasses or individuals are displayed. The Descriptions and Annotations are displayed as tool-tip. If you want, you can pin these through another option available in the tab. The properties can be viewed as tool-tip over the dashed lines of various colors connecting different nodes. You cannot pin them though.